# Can I convert an entire sheet into all caps when data is imported using IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am using a form to collect data from customers.  After submitting the form and collecting the data in Form Responses 1 (name of Google Sheet), I've created another sheet which imports most data, not all, from Form Response 1.  This sheet is called "Lilly".  I want to have all of the data that is imported from Form Data 1 onto Lilly to be all caps.  I've looked at using "UPPER", but that basically creates another cell, row, column...  I have about 12 columns of text for each form entry...  Looking for a solution...

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome. Would you please edit your question to describe the function that you use to import data from "Form Response 1"? You also mentioned that you have "about 12 columns of text for each form entry" - would you please edit your question to include a snapshot of some data on "Lilly" - if it is confidential data, then just substitute dummy data - the idea is to show what the data in each column looks like. FWIW, I think you might be on the right track with `UPPER`, but maybe you're overlooking how it could be used inside another function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To copy columns `A:L` from the `Form Responses 1` sheet to the `Lilly` sheet, and convert all data to uppercase text strings, put this formula in cell `Lilly!A1`:

```
=arrayformula( upper('Form Responses 1'!A1:L) )
```

Note that the formula has the side effect that it will convert numbers to text strings that look like numbers. To keep numbers as is while converting non-numbers to uppercase text strings, use this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    isnumber('Form Responses 1'!A1:L), 'Form Responses 1'!A1:L, 
    true, upper('Form Responses 1'!A1:L) ) 
  ) 
)
```

You should not use `importrange()` when copying data from one sheet to another within the same spreadsheet file. Use an array formula or an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) instead.